# Android AppWidget using WorkManager experiencing network issues

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-widget, android-workmanager, android-networking

I have an application in production that contains an AppWidget that schedules periodic refreshes via a WorkManager `CoroutineWorker`. My `RefreshWidgetWorker` simply requests some data from a Retrofit service & then persists that data via a Room DAO. I am receiving hundreds of crash logs of network connectivity issues & reports from users that the widget will not load for them. The exception is typically:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "[my-server]": No address associated with hostname
```

Although I've also seen:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to (port ###) from (port #####) after ####
```

The flow is as follows:

`widget onUpdate() gets called (every hour) -> check X duration since last refresh -> schedule RefreshWidgetWorker -> request from remote api -> display widget view -> persist cached data`

My `AppWidgetProvider` (paraphrasing) looks like the following:

```kotlin
override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        if (timeSinceLastRefresh >= refreshThreshold) {
              val initialWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(RefreshWidgetWorker::class.java).setInputData(/*requestData*/).build()
              WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(
                    REFRESH_WIDGET_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, initialWorkRequest
              )
        }
    }
}
```

My `RefreshWidgetWorker` looks like:

```kotlin
class RefreshWidgetWorker(val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams), KoinComponent {
    private val dataService: DataService by inject()

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val d = dataService.getData()
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).apply {
            setTextViewText(R.id.textView, d.item)
        }
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(widgetId, views)
        cache.put(d)
        return Result.success()
    }
```

And `DataService` is just a simple Retrofit service:

```kotlin
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
        .client(
            OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
        )
        .build()
        .create(DataService::class.java)
```

I've been unable to reproduce this issue on my own device & am unsure if it has to do with spotty mobile networks or a system optimization that is preventing my requests from going through. I'd appreciate any insight anyone might be able to provide as I have been stumped on this issue for a while.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I can reproduce it by scheduling the worker, for instance, with delay for next morning 8am and by that time I haven't touch my smartphone until 10am. This triggers the exception. If I check my smartphone at 8am or so, worker is triggered normally. Did you managed to sort it out?